# Where should I put onBackPressureBuffer(n) in a RxJava subscription chain?

Tags: react-native, rx-java, react-native-ble-plx

I'm trying to hotfix an existing React Native library [react-native-ble-plx](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx) adding onBackPressureBuffer() in [existing Java code](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx/blob/855e3fe5d84f18c90d84fb3543038567ece4e5cf/android/src/main/java/com/polidea/reactnativeble/BleModule.java#L1271).

I know this is ugly but I have no time to submit a PR right now and there is a [pending issue](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx/issues/299) that may solve the problem.
I'm doing this because the event emitter works at 200Hz. I need a safe way to buffer items on native side while they're consumed at their own pace on JavaScript side.

So the code becomes like the following:

```
       final Subscription subscription = Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<Observable<byte[]>>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Observable<byte[]>> call() {
                int properties = gattCharacteristic.getProperties();
                BluetoothGattDescriptor cccDescriptor = gattCharacteristic
                        .getDescriptor(Characteristic.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG_UUID);
                NotificationSetupMode setupMode = cccDescriptor != null ? NotificationSetupMode.QUICK_SETUP
                        : NotificationSetupMode.COMPAT;
                if ((properties & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) != 0) {
                    return connection.setupNotification(gattCharacteristic, setupMode);
                }

                if ((properties & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_INDICATE) != 0) {
                    return connection.setupIndication(gattCharacteristic, setupMode);
                }

                return Observable.error(new CannotMonitorCharacteristicException(gattCharacteristic));
            }
        }).onBackpressureBuffer(1000)  <---- Here is my modification
.flatMap(new Func1<Observable<byte[]>, Observable<byte[]>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<byte[]> call(Observable<byte[]> observable) {
                return observable;
            }
        }).doOnUnsubscribe(new Action0() {
            @Override
            public void call() {
                promise.resolve(null);
                transactions.removeSubscription(transactionId);
            }
        }).subscribe(new Observer<byte[]>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                promise.resolve(null);
                transactions.removeSubscription(transactionId);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                errorConverter.toError(e).reject(promise);
                transactions.removeSubscription(transactionId);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(byte[] bytes) {
                characteristic.logValue("Notification from", bytes);
                WritableArray jsResult = Arguments.createArray();
                jsResult.pushNull();
                jsResult.pushMap(characteristic.toJSObject(bytes));
                jsResult.pushString(transactionId);
                sendEvent(Event.ReadEvent, jsResult);
            }
        });
```

My problem is that even with that addition, I'm experiencing MissingBackPressure exceptions.

I've tried onBackPressureDrop() and I have exactly the same behavior. So I assume I'm doing it wrong, but can't figure out why right now.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have said you are facing an issue with an `react-native` library and the above code did throw `MissingBackpressureException` previously.

From Javadoc of `.onBackpressureDrop()` (bolding mine):

> Instructs an Observable that is emitting items faster than its observer can consume them to discard,
>   rather than emit, those items that its observer is not prepared to observe.
>
> If the downstream request count hits 0 then the Observable will refrain from calling {@code onNext} until
>   the observer invokes {@code request(n)} again to increase the request count.
>
> **Backpressure:**
>
> The operator honors backpressure from downstream and consumes the source {@code Observable} in an unbounded
>    manner (i.e., not applying backpressure to it).
>
> Scheduler:
>
> {@code onBackpressureDrop} does not operate by default on a particular {@link Scheduler}.

You can see that the next operators in the chain are `.flatMap()`, `.doOnUnsubscribe()` and `.subscribe()`.

From Javadoc of `.flatMap()` regarding backpressure:

> Backpressure:
>
> The operator honors backpressure from downstream. The outer {@code Observable} is consumed
>   in unbounded mode (i.e., no backpressure is applied to it). The inner {@code Observable}s are expected to honor
>   backpressure; if violated, the operator *may* signal {@code MissingBackpressureException}.

Javadoc `.doOnUnsubscribe()`:

> Backpressure:
>
> {@code doOnUnsubscribe} does not interact with backpressure requests or value delivery; backpressure
>   behavior is preserved between its upstream and its downstream.

And `.subscribe()`:

> Backpressure:
>
> The operator consumes the source {@code Observable} in an unbounded manner (i.e., no
>   backpressure is applied to it).

As you can see none of the operators below `.onBackpressure*()` does apply backpressure on it. You would need to add an operator that does it right after `.onBackpressure*()`. One of such operators is `.observeOn(Scheduler)`

Javadoc `.observeOn()`:

> Backpressure:
>    This operator honors backpressure from downstream and expects it from the source {@code Observable}. Violating this
>    expectation will lead to {@code MissingBackpressureException}. This is the most common operator where the exception
>    pops up; look for sources up the chain that don't support backpressure,
>    such as {@code interval}, {@code timer}, {code PublishSubject} or {@code BehaviorSubject} and apply any
>    of the {@code onBackpressureXXX} operators **before** applying applying {@code observeOn} itself.

So a workable code could look like this:

```
final Subscription subscription = Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<Observable<byte[]>>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<Observable<byte[]>> call() {
        int properties = gattCharacteristic.getProperties();
        BluetoothGattDescriptor cccDescriptor = gattCharacteristic
                .getDescriptor(Characteristic.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG_UUID);
        NotificationSetupMode setupMode = cccDescriptor != null ? NotificationSetupMode.QUICK_SETUP
                : NotificationSetupMode.COMPAT;
        if ((properties & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) != 0) {
            return connection.setupNotification(gattCharacteristic, setupMode);
        }

        if ((properties & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_INDICATE) != 0) {
            return connection.setupIndication(gattCharacteristic, setupMode);
        }

        return Observable.error(new CannotMonitorCharacteristicException(gattCharacteristic));
    }
})
.flatMap(new Func1<Observable<byte[]>, Observable<byte[]>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<byte[]> call(Observable<byte[]> observable) {
        return observable;
    }
})
.doOnUnsubscribe(new Action0() {
    @Override
    public void call() {
        promise.resolve(null);
        transactions.removeSubscription(transactionId);
    }
})
.onBackpressureBuffer(1000) // <---- Here is my modification
.observeOn(Schedulers.trampoline()) // <---- an operator that does backpressure the above
.subscribe(new Observer<byte[]>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        promise.resolve(null);
        transactions.removeSubscription(transactionId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        errorConverter.toError(e).reject(promise);
        transactions.removeSubscription(transactionId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(byte[] bytes) {
        characteristic.logValue("Notification from", bytes);
        WritableArray jsResult = Arguments.createArray();
        jsResult.pushNull();
        jsResult.pushMap(characteristic.toJSObject(bytes));
        jsResult.pushString(transactionId);
        sendEvent(Event.ReadEvent, jsResult);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'll try that and come back to you in a few hours. Stay tuned.

Comment: This seems to be working, waiting for some more days to confirm. I had no previous knowledge of implementations details of RxJava. I used to work with Reactive extensions in c# where there is buffering by default. Also, in my head, the onBackPressureBuffer would be applied downstream with nothing else required. RTFM.